# Delete all messages in a text channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make my Discord bot delete all messages in a text channel, but I can't figure out how to do it. This is what I have tried:

```py
@CLIENT.command()
async def Clear(message):
    return await CLIENT.delete_message(message)
```

I have tried other things and looked at other posts, but I have only found out that the bot will delete the message I type every time (not what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you wanted to bulk delete messages (that is, delete a number of messages at once, use `await Client.delete_messages(list_of_messages)`. Here's an example

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

Client = Bot('!')


@Client.command(pass_context = True)
async def clear(ctx, number):
    mgs = [] #Empty list to put all the messages in the log
    number = int(number) #Converting the amount of messages to delete to an integer
    async for x in Client.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit = number):
        mgs.append(x)
    await Client.delete_messages(mgs)

Client.run(Token)
```

**NOTE:** Doing this will only work for messages 14 days old and *under* and you can't delete above 100 messages at a time, meaning typing this `!clear 120` would raise an error. However, its not impossible. You can add a `while` loop in there if you really wanted to but that may produce unexpected results.

Now, what if you have messages **older** than 14 days? You can't use `Client.delete_messages(list_of_messages)`. Instead, you can use `Client.delete_message(Message)` this would delete only one message at a time. Yes, I know slow but for now, that's all we've got. So, you can modify the original code to have it delete each time it loops in the `logs_from()`.

Something like this:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

Client = Bot('!')

@Client.command(pass_context = True)
async def clear(ctx, number):
    number = int(number) #Converting the amount of messages to delete to an integer
    counter = 0
    async for x in Client.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit = number):
        if counter < number:
            await Client.delete_message(x)
            counter += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1.2) #1.2 second timer so the deleting process can be even

Client.run(Token)
```

Comment: Just for the sake of my understanding... I developed a whole Discord bot using Python and `@client.event`s (with `async def some_event`) and I have absolutely no idea what you are doing when importing Bot and passing `!` as a parameter. Is `@Client.command` the same as using `async def on_message` with `message.content.startswith`? Please enlighten me, as it seems only by looking at your short example that I could remove 100 lines of code and make my code breathe so much better while getting the exact results...

Comment: @dnLL All `@Client.command()` is, is basically just a command handler so its still just an `on_message` event listener except it parses out message content to be sure its even a command, parses out the arguments and all that jazz  so you can use `@Client.command()`. You can still only use `on_message` but you'd probably be splitting each command using `if` statements which can get filled unless you write your own command handler, up to you.

Comment: Using if statements so far. Is there any performance difference between the 2 or is there no other difference than making it easier to read?

Comment: @dnLL Hardly any performance differences. If anything, you probably save some speed using `on_message` directly but very very very minimal, mostly for readability and easier debugging. But I like to at least remove the default help command and make my own.

Comment: Why do we still have to downgrade to 3.6 version of python just to use some functions like logs_from ? Can't they just fix that?

Answer (score 8):

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@client.command(name='clear', help='this command will clear msgs')
async def clear(ctx, amount = 5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

if the number of messages to be deleted is not mentioned, by default it will delete 4 messages i.e (amount-1)

use command `-clear` or `-clear [number]` to delete the messages.
Don't use brackets in the previous line after writing 'clear'

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all of the messages in a channel using `client.logs_from(someChannel)`. From there, just use `client.delete_message(msg)`.

Using the example listed in the [readme of discord.py's](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) repo as a base, here's a method that should work for Python 3.5. Trigger this with "!clear":

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!clear'):
        tmp = await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Clearing messages...')
        async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel):
            await client.delete_message(msg)
```

Comment: im not sure whats going on now this is the first time coding with discord.py and when i run it im told " 'yield from' inside async function " not sure what im suppose to do

Comment: Oh yeah I messed that up, it should be `await` not `yield from` since `delete_message()` is not a generator. Not sure where I got that from.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for a way to delete all messages in a channel. You can use `await ctx.channel.purge()` to delete all messages in an instant.

This is an example:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

@client.command()
async def clear(ctx):
  await ctx.channel.purge()
```

Comment: Good solution here, easy to use and quick.

Comment: When no limit is provided this only clears a max of 100 messages as per [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge)

Answer (score 0):

This code will delete the bot's command and sends a success msg..

```
import asyncio

#clear
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=0):
  if amount == 0:
    fail = await ctx.send ("Please enter an amount to delete!")
  await asyncio.sleep (6)
  await fail.delete()

  if amount < 3:
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    sucess = await ctx.send (f"{amount} messages has been deleted <a:Verified:878231325469974599>") #sending success msg
    await asyncio.sleep (6) #wait 6 seconds
    await sucess.delete() #deleting the sucess msg

  else :
    if amount == 0:
    fail = await ctx.send ("Please enter an amount to delete!")
    await asyncio.sleep (6)
    await fail.delete()
```

You can use the command `-clear 12` to clear 12 messages.. Replace **12 with your number**