# python discord bot, discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: number is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord.py

i made a discord bot in python, which can clear the chat. But if I add the following command, i got this error:

My script (not everything but the command):

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clear(ctx, number):
    mgs = [] #Empty list to put all the messages in the log
    number = int(999) #Converting the amount of messages to delete to an integer
    async for x in client.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit = number):
        mgs.append(x)
    await client.delete_messages(mgs)
```

And this is the error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument number is a required argument that is missing.
```

Does somebody know, how to fix that?
Thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: Did you specify the number when calling the command? e.g. `!clear 5`

Comment: then i get this: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'logs_from'`

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? Why a method like this `logs_from` should even exist??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465082/python-discord-py-delete-all-messages-in-a-text-channel
i just copy pasted that xD

Comment: do you know how I can make a bot which clears the chat?

Comment: `logs_from` has been replaced with [`Messageable.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.history). Also this line `number = int(999)` is pointless.

Comment: You should just use [`TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge). It does the same thing in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [TextChannel.purge](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge) here is a simple example.

default number is 5 if not given, and it will only take type `int`

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, number:int = 5):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=number)
    await ctx.send(f'Cleared by {ctx.author.mention}')
```

Comment: thank you so much!!
you know by chance how to make that just the "Admin" role can run this command?

Comment: `@commands.has_any_role("Admin")` [ref](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role)

Comment: As @Fluffy added you can also use that, I added it into code. Also consider marking this as an answer if it helped.