# How to access a DM channel in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a bot that I was testing by making it send DMs to my account but now I want to delete the messages that are already sent. I have searched all over and I did not find any thing. In short I need to know how to make my bot delete it’s own messages from the command user's DM.

I try the method @Mars Buttfield-Addison told me and I am geting a error
ERROR:

```
Ignoring exception in command clear_dm:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 50, in clear_dm
    async for message in client.user.dm_channel.history(limit=messages_to_remove):
AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'dm_channel'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'dm_channel'
```

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159850/deleting-a-bots-message-in-discord-py ?

Comment: no, this is to do with dms

Comment: Yes, but it does appear that deleting messages works the same in DMs, it's just about getting a handle on the appropriate `User`s channel context via their `history` attribute: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.history

Comment: I have tryed doing it that way @Mars Buttfield-Addison but it does now work I get a error

Comment: What is the error? (This will tell whether the problem is getting a handle on the right user or finding the bot's message or something else entirely)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `dm_channel` property on a [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member) object.

Now, I don't fully understand what you are trying to say, but if you want to receive a message on a DM and check if it was on a dm, you can do:

```py
import discord
import asyncio

TOKEN = ''
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=False, members=False)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
        print("got a DM")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Now if you want to delete things, you can just access this channel like a normal one, by doing `message.channel` (you can delete, send message, or do whatever you like just like you would on a guild)

Comment: what if the dm already there and i want to delete all messages send by the bot

Comment: To delete messages, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465082/python-discord-py-delete-all-messages-in-a-text-channel). It will be similar to deleting messages on a guild channel, since both inherit from the same class and have the same shared methods. You can also delete using the [history](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.history), which is a newer way

Comment: @Hiddencoder you are accessing the `dm_channel` on the user, but like I said you have to check the channel on the message. My code works perfectly when I run it